# Apache : Directory index forbidden by Options directive:/srv/www/htdocs/testFolder

Tags: apache

Saw duplicate questions and solutions, does not seem to solve the below problem

I am trying to allow access to a folder through apache, and the /var/log/apache2/ throws the above error.

My httpd.conf is

```
# forbid access to the entire filesystem by default
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried with Options +Indexes, Options All which doesnt seem to work. Tried to change permissions of the folder too. Added a dummy index.html in the folder as well

The folder is located at /srv/www/htdocs/testFolder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to add files explicitly the files in the conf file

```
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/HDP>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar where Apache was throwing 403 error while trying to access the index.html file the issue was resolved by creating a index.hmtl in /srv/www/htdocs directory.
url: http://localhost:80/

The Suse Apache didn't create a index.html file by default don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

Change your config to

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

After that create an .htaccess file in your folder and add

```
Options +Indexes
```

to it. You probably need to reload your apache.